# Get the shortest way between two point

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shortest-path, backtracking

I have the following array:

```
steps=[
    {from:1, to:8},
    {from:1, to:2},
    {from:2, to:7},
    {from:7, to:9},
    {from:8, to:9}
];
```

this array is describe where does it has connection between two point. For example from 1 to 7 there is a way 1->2->7.

In JavaScript how can I generate the for example the shortest way from 1 to 9?

**Updated**

```
function calc_route(start, end, data)
    {           
        console.log(start+", "+end);
        console.log(data);              
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {

            if(data[i].topoint == end && data[i].frompoint == start)
            {
                console.log("Return");                  
                console.log(data[i]);
                return data[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if(data[i].frompoint == start)
                {                       
                    calcfor =   data.splice(i, 1);                                      
                    calc_route(calcfor[0].topoint, end, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I done until now, my question is how can I save the path?

Comment: In general, it appears you want a graph search. I would look at dijkstra's algorithm and A* (A Star)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function calc_route(start, end, data, mypath, solution)
        {               
            mypath.push(parseInt(start));
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
            {

                if(data[i].topoint == end && data[i].frompoint == start)
                {
                    mypath.push(end);
                    solution.push(mypath);
                    return end;
                }
                else
                {

                    if(data[i].frompoint == start)
                    {                                   
                        calcfor =   data.slice(0);  
                        calcfor.splice(i,1);                                    
                        calc_route(data[i].topoint, end, calcfor, mypath.slice(0), solution);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

The standard way to find lowest-cost paths is either the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) (which can use heuristic knowledge) or [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (which cannot). Both of these links have pseudocode that can be readily converted to Javascript.